# Getting 401 Error code while using fetch() with a custom header

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've built a custom API with AWS API Gateway.
For one of the method, I've enable the authorization to be checked using a Lambda function.
In order to make it work, I have to add the following key: `Key: authorizationToken   Value: allow`.

I've tested it using Postman and it's working fine, my POST is processed and I receive a response.

I'm just starting with Javascript so I've used the code provided in Postman.
Here it is:

```
function getData(event){
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set("authorizationToken", "allow");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    };

    fetch("https://[THE_URL_OF_MY_API]/prod/counter", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

And I'm getting the following error message in the console:

> script.js:49 POST https://[THE_URL_OF_MY_API]/prod/counter
> net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)
> getData @ script.js:49

I've looked into the logs of the API Gateway in AWS in order to troubleshoot it:

- But I can't see any logs so it seems my fetch is being block before
  it's even being sent.
- I checked the headers of the successful API call sent by Postman and I can't find any header apart from mine and the one generated by the application automatically.

What am I doing wrong ?

Note: I'm using similar code to another endpoint where the authorization is not enabled and it's working fine. So I guess my header is not correctly set.

Comment: Is this a typo? You do not include `myHeaders` in your `fetch` request!

Comment: Try adding `credentials: 'same-origin'` as fetch options

Comment: if the request is cross origin, and having a protocol and domain as part of the url suggests it is, then adding `mode: 'no-cors'` makes the response opaque - i.e. no point in `.then(response => response.text())` since there will be no response accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CRice, Salmin Skenderovic, Jaromanda X : Thanks a lot for your feedback.

The missing myHeaders was a typo, I fixed it.
Seeing the comment about the 'no-cors', I've looked into it, enable CORS, authorized my specific header in Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

And now it's working fine.

My amended code:

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set("authorizationToken", "allow");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      redirect: 'follow',
      headers : myHeaders
    };

    fetch("https://[URL_OF_MY_API_ENDPOINT]/prod/counter", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Configuration of my API Gateway:
[Configuration of my API Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwpcU.png)